# i cant run a function from a class

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

i get this error every time i try to move paddle at right direction !!

> Uncaught TypeError: paddle.moveRight is not a function at HTMLDocument.InputHandler.document.addEventListener.event

//index.html

```
<html>
<head>title>Brick Breaker</title
    ><meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>  
    <canvas id="gameScreen" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

//index.js

```
import Paddle from './paddle.js'
import InputHandler from './input.js'
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let paddle = new Paddle();
new InputHandler(Paddle)

function gameLoop() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

  paddle.update();
  paddle.draw(ctx);

  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
gameLoop()
```

//paddle.js

```
    export default class Paddle {
  constructor(){
    this.width=150;
    this.height=30;

    this.maxSpeed =10;
    this.speed=0;

    this.position={
        x:300,
        y:500 
    }
}
  moveRight() {
    this.speed = this.maxSpeed;
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
    ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

  update() {
    this.position.x += this.speed;
  }
}
```

//input.js

```
export default class InputHandler {
  constructor(paddle) {

    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {

        if(event.keyCode ==37)
        paddle.moveRight();
    });
  }
}
```

---

the paddle should go to right when i press the right arrow button

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: paddle.moveRight is not a function` You do not have `moveRight` defined anywhere, so thus `paddle.moveRight is not a function`...

Comment: I do not see `moveRight` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don't see you using paddle.moveRight() anywhere in your code. Add a moveright function, and copy your code that tests for the key pressed. (The keycode for the right arrow key is 39). Also, in your index.html file you are missing a '<' in the first title tag.

Comment: i am sorry for that silly mistake
i just edited my question now
**i meant right  not left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let paddle = new Paddle();
new InputHandler(Paddle)
```

You are passing the `Paddle` class into the constructor of `InputHandler`. You are then calling `moveLeft` on that class.

You probably meant to pass in the instance of the class.

```
let paddle = new Paddle();
new InputHandler(paddle);
```

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: Pass the `paddle` instance into the `InputHandler`, like I did in my second code block above. `new InputHandler(paddle)` rather than `new InputHandler(Paddle)`

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!!
i don't know how to thank you man!
i spent about 6 hours trying to fix this,and the error was to chang P to p !!!!

Comment: No problem! It can be hard to notice these things when you're in the weeds of writing code :)